# How to use fnmatch

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to use the [fnmatch](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html) function from `fnmatch.h`

`printf("match: %i") ,fnmatch("hello", "hello world", 0);`

The above prints a large negative number. How should the call look like?

Comment: any returned value, other than 0, means the match failed.  0 means the two strings matched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You accidentally used C's comma operator.  I think you want to pass the return value of `fnmatch` to `printf`, so you should change that line to:

```
printf("match: %i", fnmatch("hello", "hello world", 0));
```